# PHP file upload works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am making a website that takes an audio file that is uploaded from a user, mixes it on my server and downloads it back to the users device, but it won't upload the file anymore. Initially I was running the website on my windows server but it for some reason struggled with getting the SSL certificate, so I had to build it from the ground up on Linux RHE.
To simplify the issue, I got a bare-bone file uploading script which also worked on my Windows port, but not on this server. The only response I got was "Error moving the uploaded file!", meaning something to do with the /tmp directory I assume and not being able to move it from there? I did look in the directory and it was pretty much empty, not the uploaded files. Here is the code.

```
`<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Check if the file was uploaded without errors
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // Get the temporary filename
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $targetDir = '/var/www/html/';
        $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile)) {
            echo 'File uploaded and moved successfully.'; //I get this error
        } else {
            echo 'Error moving the uploaded file.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error uploading file. Error code: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>`
```

I tested the same code on windows (with different directories of course) and it worked. I changed the permissions in the /tmp directory, chown, chmod.. I have made it print errors with $_FILES['file']['error'] which returned "0", meaning no error.

The expected outcome should be a "file uploaded successfully" and the file uploads to the websites directory for the other code to mix it.

Comment: /var/www/html/ is the default directory of httpd, usually a domain will not be residing in this directory and will NOT have permissions to access files in this directory (unless you grant the permissions) . Please double-check

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the problem is in the destination path, we must modify the permissions of
`/var/www/html/` too

Another possible problem is that you are using the original file name, which can cause an error if there is already a file with the same name.

Comment: Thank you, so the permissions should be 1777 and owned by Apache ?

Comment: I think so, I have never used my application in linux so I don't know which user it corresponds to

Comment: I tried changing permissions and still no luck. Just says the same thing "error moving uploaded file"

Comment: Change the path and try moving it to desktop to see if it's a permissions issue. You can also try to modify the destination path by an absolute path

Comment: Thank you Julian, I have found the error codes here. I tried changing the ownership and permissions but the same errors are staying. What do you recommend for the paths? Here are the codes. Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/audiofiles/TNC_Interview.mp3): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/phpupload.php on line 17

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/phpyFVcIu" to "/var/www/html/audiofiles/TNC_Interview.mp3" in /var/www/html/phpupload.php on line 17

Comment: You can use this line to see the folder permissions `ls -l /var/www/html/audiofiles`. 
You should also verify that the file you are trying to make the modification has permissions to do so `ls -l /var/www/html/phpupload.php`. 
According to the error line it seems that the phpupload.php file does not have permissions to modify the folder